# Type of dialog in React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, dialog

I'm trying to make a modal in React TypeScript and I can't figure out the exact type of a reference of a HTML dialog.

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

const Modal: React.FC = () => {
  const modalRef = useRef<any>(null)
  
  function openModal() {
    modalRef.current.showModal()
  }

  function closeModal() {
    modalRef.current.close()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={openModal}>Open<button/>
      <dialog ref={modalRef}>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Info</p>
        <button onClick={closeModal}>Close<button/>
      </dialog>
    <div/>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

Could anyone help me figure out the right type I would put in place of `any`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most html components are just `HTML${componentName}Element`,
for example `HTMLDivElement` and in your case `HTMLDialogElement`

```
const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null)
```

Comment: HTMLDialogElement is not working, react says it is deprecated and I get this error when I use: Property 'showModal' does not exist on type 'HTMLDialogElement'. ts(2339)
Same error for close.

Comment: @LeandroAntunes
it is fixed in typescript 4.7
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/pull/1259